# How can I access open data on the Indian rupee value, inflation and sensex index over time?

Tags: data-request, economics, india

I would like to have an open data source on inflation, rupee value and sensex index data over period of 10 years of India.

Comment: Would suggest refining the title here - currently somewhat misleading.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Trading Economic provides information about [India inflation over the years](http://www.tradingeconomics.com/india/inflation-cpi) (apparently registered users can export this data).

Google finance provides the [Rupee value](https://www.google.com/finance?q=CURRENCY%3AINR&ei=qiiLUcj_IYKOwAOUaQ) over th years and [you can download](https://support.google.com/finance/answer/71913?hl=en) this as a csv file.

Google finance also provides [SENSEX](https://www.google.com/finance?q=INDEXBOM%3ASENSEX&ei=PCuLUcCiM4KOwAOUaQ) data.

Comment: unfortunately, currencies in google finance (no longer) have a historical export option. Those interested may find good answers here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12115819/2327328 or here: http://opendata.stackexchange.com/a/1676/1511

Answer (score 3):

India has an active open data site at http://data.gov.in with 605 datasets as of today. [Some of those](http://data.gov.in/catalogs/?filter=catalog_type%3acatalog_type_raw_data%2bagency:3731&sort=updated%20desc) are about finance, and [this one](http://data.gov.in/dataset/india-macro-economic-indicators-summary-table) is related to inflation.

The government of India continues to publish additional datasets.

Comment: The title of this question was inaccurate and has been corrected; the asker was clearly interested in a rather specific set of financial data.

Answer (score 0):

Answer to primary question, not particular options that are mentioned

1. Census of India http://censusindia.gov.in/
2. Meteorological data  http://www.imdpune.gov.in/
3. World bank data for India http://data.worldbank.org/country/india
4. Water related data from NGO http://www.indiawaterportal.org/data
5. Ministry of Finance , Economic data http://finmin.nic.in/stats_data/nsdp_sdds/index.html

Comment: The title of this question was not accurate; asker was clearly interested in the specific data mentioned.